# Selecting a single pair of users

Tags: sql, self-join

I have a database with transactions between users. I want to keep an undirected table of each relationship between users, so combine the transaction of user A to user B with the one from user B to user A. I think it can be done with a self join but I have no clue how to start.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: (1) Provide sample data.  (2) Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Most databases support `greatest()` and `least()` functions.  If you want to get undirected pairs of users, you can use:

```
select least(a, b), greatest(a, b)
from t
group by least(a, b), greatest(a, b);
```